# how can add number to integerField in django models?

Tags: python, django

I have a django model like this :

```
class Post(models.Model):
      pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
      featured = models.booleanField(default=False)
      num = models.IntegerField(defualt = 0, null=True,blank=True)

      def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
          if self.featured is not None:
             self.pub_date = timezone.now()
             self.featured = False
             self.num = ++1
          super (Post,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Infact I want to add number in my num field when the timezone is updated
but this line `self.num = ++1` isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python does not support `++` operation and does not use it in that way. Fix your code like this.

```
self.num = ++1 # (X)
self.num += 1 # (O)
```